# Postgres Bit Variant equivalent data type in Java

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I Have a Postgres sql database with data in it. Im trying to insert data from my Spring-Data-JPA project with Hibernate mappings. I am getting

```
ERROR: org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - ERROR: column "is_active" is of type bit varying but expression is of type oid
```

Here is my entity

```
@Entity
@Table(schema = "shard_1", name = "pages")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({ @NamedQuery(name = "Pages.findAll", query = "SELECT p FROM Pages p"),
        @NamedQuery(name = "Pages.findById", query = "SELECT p FROM Pages p WHERE p.id = :id"),
        @NamedQuery(name = "Pages.findByPageNumber", query = "SELECT p FROM Pages p WHERE p.pageNumber = :pageNumber"),
        @NamedQuery(name = "Pages.findByTitle", query = "SELECT p FROM Pages p WHERE p.title = :title"),
        @NamedQuery(name = "Pages.findBySectionId", query = "SELECT p FROM Pages p WHERE p.sectionId = :sectionId"),
        @NamedQuery(name = "Pages.findByVersionId", query = "SELECT p FROM Pages p WHERE p.versionId = :versionId"),
        @NamedQuery(name = "Pages.findByCreated", query = "SELECT p FROM Pages p WHERE p.created = :created"),
        @NamedQuery(name = "Pages.findByModified", query = "SELECT p FROM Pages p WHERE p.modified = :modified"),
        @NamedQuery(name = "Pages.findByPdfcontent", query = "SELECT p FROM Pages p WHERE p.pdfcontent = :pdfcontent") })
public class Pages implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private Long id;
    @Column(name = "page_number")
    private Integer pageNumber;
    @Column(length = 2147483647)
    private String title;
    @Column(name = "section_id")
    private BigInteger sectionId;
    @Column(name = "version_id")
    private BigInteger versionId;
    @Lob
    @Column(name = "is_active")
    private Object isActive;
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date created;
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date modified;
    @Column(length = 2147483647)
    private String pdfcontent;
}
```

This is my postgres table

```
CREATE TABLE shard_1.pages
(
    id bigint NOT NULL DEFAULT shard_1.id_generator(),
    page_number integer,
    title text COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    section_id bigint,
    version_id bigint,
    is_active bit varying,
    created timestamp without time zone,
    modified timestamp without time zone,
    pdfcontent text COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    CONSTRAINT pages_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
WITH (
    OIDS = FALSE
)
TABLESPACE pg_default;

ALTER TABLE shard_1.pages
    OWNER to root;
```

I tried Java datatypes boolean, string, char array, int, byte[] but fails with everything. What datatype for the field is_active should I use here?

Comment: Why don't you use a `boolean` column for a flag like `is_active`? And why is that annotated as `@Lob` and not `@Boolean`?

Comment: Using @ Lob was yet another try that I gave. Didn't really work. Not sure about the @ Boolean existence

Comment: `private  isActive;` should be `private boolean isActive;` as well

Comment: Tried the same, but didn't work.

Comment: `@Column(name = "is_active") private Boolean isActive;` works for me (if the column is properly defined as `boolean` in the database)

Comment: Hi, The database is already built and its of type bit varying in postgres. Hence i couldn't alter anything in the database end. Just need to alter the Java side code in respect to it

Comment: You should _really_ change the database model. Using `bit` for a boolean column is a bad choice.

Comment: Okay, The DB is already in production, used with another application. Thats the reason, i couldnt change the structure.  Let me try with other options.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove @Lob , i.e :

```
@Column(name = "is_active")
private Boolean isActive;
```

And alter your table 'shard_1.pages' just like this :

```
ALTER TABLE shard_1.pages DROP COLUMN is_active;
ALTER TABLE shard_1.pagese ADD COLUMN is_active boolean;
```

Comment: There is no need to drop the column, just to change its data type